# laravel routes.php dynamic url

Tags: url, laravel, laravel-routing

I have three urls:

```
localhost:8000/oc/online-marketing/ppc
localhost:8000/websystems/online-marketing/ppc
localhost:8000/all/online-marketing/ppc
```

and I need dynamic settings for each URL.

Before that, I've used to have the route.php like this:

```
Route::get('oc/online-marketing/ppc', function()
{
    $users = User::where('client_id', 1)->get();
    return View::make('users')->with('users', $users);
});
```

But I must set dynamic url like this: `Route::get('{project}/{module}/{submodule}', ... );`
where `project` is `oc` or `websystems` or all

The `module` is `online-marketing`

The `submodule` is `ppc`

The project name `oc`, `websystems` or `all` could be in table named `users`

How can I achieve that by using controllers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try something like foillowing, declare the `Route` like this:

```
Route::get('{project}/{module}/{submodule}', array('as' => 'mycontroller.project', 'uses' => 'MyController@project'));
```

Create the `Controller`:

```
class MyController extends BaseController {
    public function project($project, $module, $submodule)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's something to get you started with ...

In your routes.php file, you can have something like:

```
Route::get('/{clientID}', array('uses' => 'SomeController@someFunction'));
```

And in the SomeController.php file:

```
public function someFunction($clientID)
{
            $users = User::where('client_id', $clientID)->get();
            return View::make('users')->with('users', $users);
}
```

For more information, refer to http://laravel.com/docs/routing#route-parameters